# Unable to use rust crates

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm new to rust. I'm following a getting started tutorial that imports the crate [random-number](https://crates.io/crates/random-number) but when running the code I'm getting the error `can't find crate for 'random_number'`. What am I doing wrong?

`~/Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "test"
version = "0.0.1"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
random-number = "0.1.8"
```

`~/src/main.rs`:

```rust
extern crate random_number;
use random_number::random;

fn main() {
    let num: i8 = random!(..);
    println!("{}", num);
}
```

Comment: How are you running your code?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but you don't need the `extern crate` line in new versions of rust.

Comment: Works with `cargo run` on `cargo 1.64.0 (387270bc7 2022-09-16)` / `rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)` on an m1 macbook pro 2021

Comment: If you're getting that error in your IDE, it's because you haven't run `cargo build` or `cargo run`, which installs the crates if they aren't already.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it was very helpful.

@kmdreko In the beginning I was running `rustc src/main.rs && ./main`, but now I'm using `cargo build && cargo run`. 

@Holloway Thanks for the tip.

@Samathingamajig Thanks a bunch. I have run `cargo build` and `cargo run` and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rustc` is not meant to be used directly. It is the compiler that can compile a `.rs` file, but it doesn't have any dependency manager attached to it. So if you decide to use `rustc` directly, you need to manage your dependencies manually.

`cargo` is the official tool to compile Rust projects. It internally uses `rustc`, but additionally manages the project's dependencies that are specified in `Cargo.toml`.

```bash
cargo build --release && ./target/release/<project_name>
```

or the short form:

```bash
cargo run --release
```